# Advantages to using a salt for a login system?

Tags: php, authentication, token

I would like to build my own login system to be as secure as possible.
Encrypting passwords with MD5 and stripping extra data with

```
$password = strip_tags($password);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);
$password = md5($password);
```

I've seen tokens in some examples but dont really understand the usefulness.
edit - I was corrected and it is salts and not tokens I have seen.

Comment: If you don't know the difference between a salt and a token and you don't know that MD5 is a hashing algorithm and not an encryption algorithm, then there is no way your login system is going to be secure. You have a lot of reading to do, but well done for asking.

Comment: Correct! This has already helped me quite a bit :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its not called a token, its called a salt.

If we don't salt the password, you could have duplicate password hashes.

If I and someone else has the same password (lets say StackOverflow)

- Me - `StackOverflow` - `84d7dc19766c446f5e4084e8fce87f82`
- Someone else - `StackOverflow` - `84d7dc19766c446f5e4084e8fce87f82`

But with a salt,

- Me - `StackOverflowMeSalt` - `9a0126445be2d0b0bc6ab9728aae1323`
- Someone else - `StackOverflowSomeone elseSalt` - `66f6bd8d92f084dabd7e2dd588b2bfcb`

Also, theres no need to use `mysql_real_escape_string` or `strip_tags` on a password when its hashed. This will make the passwords more insecure.

Answer (score 4):

A salt adds an extra layer of security - the md5 hash can no longer be looked up in a Reverse MD5 Database.

For example, if someone hacks your website that is using only md5($password) (password is 'somepassword'), he can lookup your password in a [Reverse MD5 Database](http://www.md5decrypter.com/) which use [rainbow tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table), and it will show up as plain text. But with a salt (salt is 'W*&sju'), the plain text actually comes out to be 'W*&sjusomepassword' and won't be found in an online database.

So on your server, hash your password with the salt before you input it to your database:

```
md5($password . 'somesalT&^@*!');
```

Then to check password on login:

```
$hashed_password = md5($_POST['password'] . 'somesalt&^@*!');
```

Recommendations:

- hard code the salt, so even if someone were to get database access, they won't have your salt... making your hash even more secure.
- Salt should be at least 3 characters long, upper, lower, and special
  characters.
- Require the password to be atleast 7 characters long.
  So this will leave you with a 10 character long, upper, lower, special character password hash.

Comment: this is very helpful for my understanding of why salts are used.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why you would use a salt is because [rainbow tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) exist.

For example, the MD5 hash of `password123` is `482c811da5d5b4bc6d497ffa98491e38`.

If the above hash was discovered in your database, it could be compared against a table of known hashes in which `password123` may exist. Therefore, if a match is found, the plain text password will be known.

If however, you use a salt that is only known to you, such as `mY_r4nD0m_Sa1t`, when you do the following:

```
md5($password.$salt);
```

This will produce a hash of `f5a299746a9dbc005e423259283bc56b` which is completely different to the known hash of `password123` above.

In all cases though, I'd recommend that you use [phpass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/).

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, it's called 'salt'.
Normally you encrypt the login details with a password in the PHP and generate a random salt. The salt is then stored in the database with the encrypted login details and used when decrypting. Basically it makes the password random for each user.